# SQL query to find duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table 1 which has IND_REF and CODE columns:

[image]

I would like to find duplicate codes.

I want to have the below image for output:

[image]

I would appreciate if someone could help me or guide me how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregation with `GROUP BY` is probably the easiest way here:

```
SELECT IND_REF, CODE
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY IND_REF, CODE
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Indeed. Thank you for your answer, I have figured it out too. Much appriciated your time.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this using having clause.

```
SELECT IL.IND_REF,IL.CODE 
FROM TABLE1 IL 
WHERE IL.TYPE=12 
group by IL.IND_REF,IL.CODE 
having COUNT(*)>1
```

Comment: @DaleK I tried to accept this but as the answer was less then 5 mins it didnt allowed me, i know that. I have accepted his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest way is to select on count:

```
SELECT [IND_REF], [CODE]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY [IND_REF] // add [CODE] if u like different codes to be mapped to the same [IND_REF]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

should do the work

Answer (score 0):

Always bring your sample data as text - so that we can copy-paste it into one or more SQL statements

Like here, where I re-typed it by hand:

```
WITH
input(ind_ref,code) AS (
          SELECT 1234,12
UNION ALL SELECT 1234,13
UNION ALL SELECT 1222,12
UNION ALL SELECT 1222,11
UNION ALL SELECT 1333,12
UNION ALL SELECT 1333,12
UNION ALL SELECT 1333,13
)
-- then, as @Biswanath Das did, continue like this:
SELECT
  ind_ref
, code
FROM input
GROUP BY
  ind_ref
, code
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

returning:

```
 ind_ref | code 
---------+------
    1333 |   12
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case we can use "GROUP BY" and "HAVING"

```
SELECT IND_REF, CODE, COUNT(IND_REF) as duplicate_count
FROM `table_name`
GROUP BY IND_REF
HAVING duplicate_count > 1
```